# Accessing Large buffer from Device through DMA

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to know how the device,cpu and os work together when we want to transfer large data like 10GB(more than the RAM available) from a DMA capable device. After doing some browsing on internet i came to know the following two approaches.

> 1. Using IOMMU ( it converts the device address to physical address)
> 2. Copying buffers to and from the peripheral's addressable memory space.

I read some relevant stackoverflow articles that we can increase dma size on boot-time, but I want to know about very large buffer which cannot fit in memory. Are  these approaches proper?

Comment: You don't have to transfer it all at once... Large data is usually transferred in quite small chunks, and processed in batches.  For example, get 1MB at a time, stream it to disk, or out the network, or extract useful information from it in real time and discard it, etc.  If this is missing your question, please add a more specific example.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your time! .This is what I wanted to know.I thought there is some different mechanism which is followed for large chunks to optimize. Yes I understand now that it is transfer is done in small chunk. The chunk to be transfered is copied to DMA addressable area.